# Prevent transform on position: fixed parent element from collapsing height

Tags: html, css

If there exists children set with a height of 100%, and a `transform` is set on its `position: fixed` parent, the parent completely loses its height and collapses.

For example

```css
.wrapper {
  transform: scale(1);  
}

.inner {
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  margin: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 300px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you remove the `transform: scale(1);` on `.wrapper`, the document flows as desired.

One workaround I've found is instead of using 100% height on `.inner`, use `100vh`, but that [introduces other complications on mobile Safari and Chrome](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/articles/2015/02/18/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers/).

1. Why does `transform` applied to a fixed element collapse its children?
2. What alternatives exist such that I can apply a transform to a fixed element without the result of its children collapsing?

Comment: the first duplicate explain the why --> the wrapper will become the new containing block of the fixed element. The second duplicate will explain why in this case the height collpase because percentage height will fail since there is no height define on wrapper

Comment: TL;DR, use `vh` unit instead of percetange for the height --> `height: calc(100vh - 160px);`

Comment: Just add `display: contents;` to the `.wrapper`

Comment: sorry, did a wrong copy/paste .. first duplicate is fixed now with the correct link